# Get all the documents list in Alfresco Repository with Folder Locations

Tags: alfresco

Is there a way for me to be able to get the list of documents in Alfresco Repository with their corresponding folder locations?

Comment: Depends where you code is running and how it is talking to Alfresco? The answer for Java code running on the repo (eg an action or custom webscript) is very different to external code using CMIS or the public API...

Comment: Yes, of course. What is your preferred programming language or API? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for? - https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes/listNodeChildren